# Volume goes to zero and then fades in to new volume when increased or decreased

Tags: windows-7, audio, dell-latitude

Whenever I increase or decrease my laptop's volume after not changing it for a while, it will go to zero volume (it won't actually on the slider, just the audio) and then fade in to the new volume.

It's been very annoying, and I haven't been able to find anything with internet searches. I thought it could be a feature of my laptop, but I couldn't find any clear options for it. (Windows 7 Dell Latitude E6540) Does anyone know how do I can disable or fix it? Another person I know with this laptop also had this problem.

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS and drivers from Dell's website?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll look into it. Would that fix it?

Comment: Looking at the audio driver and BIOS updates on Dell's website and the fixes/enhancements, it doesn't look like it was fixed or changed.

Comment: I don't think you can completely rely on the info you are looking at. It may not fix anything. But the good news is that it is really unlikely to harm anything.  So, I recommend updating the BIOS and all the drivers. It may fix your issue, or may fix other issues you weren't sure you had. This is just the most common thing to try in your situation.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the only thing I can do. Thanks!